# Scala class lazy val variables strange behaviour with Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I noticed a strange behaviour while using Spark for a project using scala 2.10, I am reading a properties file and writes all the content inside a Map (loadConfig) and I also created a simple method that returns the value of a given key.

The problem is, when I get all the blackListed names in a `lazy val` class variable, the `namesBlackList` appears to be empty beacause all of my `Person` have the "full access" tag, wich is not correct

However, when i write `namesBlackList` **inside** `filterAccess` then everything works perfectly well.

**ConfigManager.scala**

```
object ConfigManager extends Serializable {

  private var configMap = Map.empty[String, String]

  def loadConfig(configPath:String) = {
    // Reads a key/value properties file and writes it in the configmap
  }

  def getParameter(parameter: String): String = configMap.getOrElse(parameter, s"${parameter}=>UNKNOWN")
}
```

**AnalyseData.scala**

```
object AnalyseData extends Serializable {

    private lazy val namesBlackList = ConfigManager.getParameter("names.blacklist").toSet

    def filterAccess(rdd:RDD[Person]) : RDD[Person] = {
        rdd.map {person => 
          if (namesBlackList.contains(person.firstName))
            (person.firstName,person.lastName,"limited access")
          else
            (person.firstName,person.lastName,"full Access")  
       }
    }
}
```

**AnalyseService.scala**

```
object AnalyseService extends Serializable {
    def main(path:String) {
        ConfigManager.loadConfig(path)

        val datas = createNameRdd // reads from a db and create a RDD[Person]

        val filteredData = AnalyseData.filterAccess(datas)

    }
}
```

I tried to tweak everything in my code and it appears that, since Spark execute the `map` method in a `lazy` way, setting the result of a Singleton object in a `lazy val` class variable will not produce the correct result. 
I can't understand why it is not working and more importantly, I can't really find how to fix this besides calling `namesBlackList` inside a method

Thanks for your comments.

Comment: It seems like your ConfigManager is not yet ready when the `namesBlackList` value is initialized. Do you know when it's initialized? Can you show the body of the `excludeNames` method i.e. the case where it works?

Comment: I did a mistake while writing my post, excludeNames is actually filterAccess, see my edited post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#understanding-closures-a-nameclosureslinka for explanation of some terms and concepts required. What happens in your case (I think):

1. `ConfigManager.loadConfig(path)` runs on the driver node. `configMap` is initialized there.
2. In `filterAccess`, `namesBlackList` is really a method call. So, when the code inside `map` is executed on the worker nodes, this call happens there and accesses `configMap` on the same node, which is empty.
3. However, when you "write namesBlackList inside filterAccess" then it is a local variable and it *does* become part of the closure, and is serialized.

To resolve this, you need to use a [broadcast variable](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#broadcast-variables) for `configMap`. Something like

```
object ConfigManager extends Serializable {

  private var configMap: Broadcast[Map[String, String]] = _

  def loadConfig(configPath:String) = {
    // Reads a key/value properties file and writes it in the configmap
  }

  def getParameter(parameter: String): String = configMap.value.getOrElse(parameter, s"${parameter}=>UNKNOWN")
}
```

Even better to avoid `var`:

```
def main(path:String) {
    val configMap = ConfigManager.loadConfig(path)

    val datas = createNameRdd(configMap) // reads from a db and create a RDD[Person]

    val filteredData = AnalyseData.filterAccess(datas, configMap)
}
```

Comment: That explains why my unit tests worked and not the program itself when I run it in a two node cluster. thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could try forcing the `lazy val` inside the `filterAccess` method (but outside the closure) like so:

```
object AnalyseData extends Serializable {

  private lazy val namesBlackList = ConfigManager.getParameter("names.blacklist").toSet

  def filterAccess(rdd:RDD[Person]) : RDD[Person] = {
      val localNamesBlackList = namesBlackList       //force the lazy val...
      rdd.map {person => 
        if (localNamesBlackList.contains(person.firstName))
          (person.firstName,person.lastName,"limited access")
        else
          (person.firstName,person.lastName,"full Access")  
     }
  }
}
```